# Image not getting aligned properly with materialize css card

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using materialize css for placing images inside cards

But the images seem to get cut at half

```html
<div class="card teal lighten-3 large hoverable">
    <div class="card-image">
        <img id="axolotl-api-picture" style="background-size: 100% 100%;" alt="cute axolotl">
    </div>
    <div class="card-action teal">
        <a class="prev axolotl-api-picture">Previous</a>
        <a class="next axolotl-api-picture">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The current image:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkp7E.png)

The orginal image(i.e. what I want):
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrSgF.jpg)

So you see the image is not completely showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
style="background-size: cover;"
```

Also I think you need to change the height of this div `<div class="card-image">`.The image is taking up the whole space available to it.

Comment: Isn't that just the same thing? what I am doing

Comment: It doesn't work though. Just gives the same result